Bashrc not working with new users

As you can see in the picture, any user unless the first one has the prompt destroyed I don't know why.
I changed the ps1 (both with forced color and without it) and did not change.
Is there a change anyone of you can fix this?
Thank you

Assuming you created the users using useradd -m, and that you set their shell to Bash; a corrupt /etc/skel/.bashrc file could be the culprit, as new users' ~/.bashrc file is a straight copy of that file.

Here's my untouched 24.04 /etc/skel/.bashrc for reference: https://pastebin.com/8tt6fBEG

That looks like exactly what you'd get if you try to use the default bash PS1 in a dash (/bin/sh) shell - for example because you exported PS1 to the environment in which you ran su iker-t command. Does the behavior change if you invoke a login shell instead (e.g. su -l iker-t)?

Please [edit] your question and tell us i) your operating system, ii) how you are connecting to this system (it looks like you are using putty from Windows, is that correct?), iii) what shell each of the users is using (bash? dash? sh? fish? zsh?), iv) the output of echo "$PS1" for each user, both the one for whom the prompt is OK, and for the other one.
